# How can I get the amount of clicks per ad using facebooks marketing API php SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I want to print out the name of my ads and the amount of clicks they have gotten. All my ads are in the `$ads` array.

```
foreach ($ads as $ad){
    $adinsights = $ad->getInsights( array (
        AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS
        ));
    echo $ad->{AdFields::NAME}.PHP_EOL;
    echo $adinsights->{AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS}.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The code above only prints out the names of the ads.

`$adinsights->{AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS}.PHP_EOL` resolves into an empty string `""`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function returns a collection of AdInsight objects, so you're going to have to iterate them to get the output:

```
foreach ($ads as $ad){
  $adinsights = $ad->getInsights( array (
    AdsInsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS
  ));

  foreach($adinsights as $a){
    echo $a->date_start . ' - ' . $a->date_stop . ': ' . $a->inline_link_clicks.PHP_EOL;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! Funny thing is I figured it out about 3 minutes before you answered and was in the middle of writing an answer myself. The function returns a Cursor object which could be a collection of AdInsight objects, but actually only is one AdInsights object since each Ad object corresponds to only one AdInsights object. So If I am not mistaken the foreach loop is just a way of accessing the AdInsights object inside the Cursor object.